# VAT charge in the EU

Tags: taxes, payments, invoices, vat

A transport company in Brazil are providing me services for transport within the EU. I am based on the EU will I have to pay VAT when invoiced?

Comment: It depends on many factors. Do you represent a legal entity or are you an individual? Is the Brazilian company operating legally in the EU? How do they pay taxes? How do they operate? You need to provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

Probably yes. When in doubt, you are probably responsible for registering for VAT. Ask you tax adviser or local financial authorities for details.